# How to move views to a different Size Class in the Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, size-classes

I inadvertently added all of my views to a storyboard view controller using the wrong size class (Any Width-Regular Height). I meant to do it in wAny hAny. Do I have to delete them and start over in AnyAny or is there a way to transfer them in IB?

I see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27529612/3681880) that it is possible to go in and edit a file, but that seems like a hack and not any easier than just adding them all over again. Is there a way to do it within Xcode itself?

Comment: Isn't the `installed` option for constraints? What about the views themselves before constraints have been added? I couldn't find an option for that.